# Update Returning Order by in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a query updating rows in a table. I want the query to update the rows and return the rows affected.

Currently I have

```
UPDATE employees SET name = 'John' RETURNING employees.*;
```

This works fine. But what if I want to return the rows affected in a specified order. Something like

```
UPDATE employees SET name = 'John' RETURNING employees.* ORDER BY name ASC;
```

This does not work. Anyone got a good suggestion?

Comment: Where is your `WHERE` clause? Do you want to update every name in the employee database to 'John'?

Comment: its just an example am giving

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This can be done using a data modifying CTE (common table expression):

```
with updated as (
    UPDATE employees 
        SET name = 'John' 
    RETURNING *
)
select *
from updated
ORDER BY empname ASC;
```

Comment: Thats super brillant!!! It works. Thanks. Would give a thousand votes if I could.