# Postgres RETURNING clause with join and order

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update, sql-order-by

I've got this query that updates some rows and returns the updated rows in the `RETURNING` clause. However, even though I've specified `ORDER BY mycolumn` in the inner query, the rows returned by `RETURNING` aren't ordered.

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 'A'
FROM
  (
    SELECT id FROM mytable
    WHERE status = 'B'
    ORDER BY mycolumn
    LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE
  ) sub
  JOIN jointable j ON j.id = sub.id
WHERE mytable.id = sub.id
RETURNING *
```

I tried putting an `ORDER BY` in the outer query, like after the `JOIN` or after the `WHERE`, but I get an error in both cases. How can I make it return the rows in the desired order?

(A similar question was answered in [Update Returning Order by in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649976/update-returning-order-by-in-postgresql) but that doesn't include JOINs, only ORDER.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CTE:

```
WITH updated as(
    UPDATE mytable SET status = 'A'
FROM
  (
    SELECT id FROM mytable
    WHERE status = 'B'
    ORDER BY mycolumn
    LIMIT 100
    FOR UPDATE
  ) sub
  JOIN jointable j ON j.id = sub.id
WHERE mytable.id = sub.id
RETURNING *
)
select *
from updated
ORDER BY mycolumn
```

Comment: I get an error `ORDER BY "mycolumn" is ambiguous`. If I take out the last `ORDER BY`, there's no error. So the inner `ORDER BY` is fine, it's the outer one that gives the error. I suppose it's because both tables in the join have a `mycolumn`. How can I get the ordering to work then?

Comment: Instead of RETURNING *, write down the columns you need.

Comment: For example: RETURNING j.id, sub.mycolumn, remember that you have to use specific aliases